# Unidentified index issue

Tags: php, html

Why is it registering this as an error, when i try to $_GET actual_quote and poster, it returns this.
Notice: Undefined index: actual_quote in the index of the file on line 47
Call Stack
    Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0004  254200  {main}( )   ..\stupid.php:0

the $_GET actual_quote is on line 47, and it says the same for poster, please help I am stuck as hell on this.

```
    <form name = "quoted" form action = "question.php" method="get">
    <input id = "poster" type="text" name="poster" required="required" placeholder = "Credited Individual.">     
    <br>
    <textarea class = "actual_quote" name = "actual_quote" required="required" placeholder = "Write the question here!"></textarea>
    <br><br><br>

    <div class = "checkboxes" required="required">
        <h3 style = "margin-top:-20px;">Please select one catagory that the quote falls into.</h3>
        <label for="x"><input type="radio" name="x" value="stupid" id = "x" checked="checked" action = "stupid.php" /><span>stupid</span></label>
        <br>
        <label for="x"><input type="radio" name="x" value="stupider" id = "x" action = "stupider.php" /><span>stupider</span></label>
        <br>
        <label for="x"><input type="radio" name="x" value="stupidest" id = "x" action = "stupidest.php" /><span>stupidest</span></label>
    </div>

    <input id = "submit1" type="submit"><br>
 </form>
```

and here's the php on each of the pages, stupid, stupider, and stupidest, the php error is saying that actual-quote and poster are not identified indexes, help?

```
    <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="submissions">
    <div class="logo-logo"><h2>Question.</h2>
    <div class="checkboxes"><?= !empty($_GET['x']) ? $_GET['x'] : '' ?>
    </div>

    </div>

 <div class="top-submit"><?php echo '&#8220;' . (!empty($_GET['actual_quote']) ?  $_GET['actual_quote'] : '') . '&#8221;'; $actual_quote = $_GET['actual_quote'];?>
 </div>
 <div class="poster"><?php echo "-" .  (!empty($_GET['poster']) ? $_GET['poster'] :''); $poster =  $_GET['poster'];?>
 <div class = "like">
 <a href = "javascript:countClicksLike();" class = "btn btn-large" style = "color:green;">Like</a>
 <p id = "like" style = "color:green;">0</p>
 </div>
 <div class = "dislike">
 <a href = "javascript:countClicks();" class = "btn btn-large" style = "float:right; color:red;">Dislike</a>
 <p id = "dis" style = "color:red;">0</p>
 </div>
  </div>
 <?php 
 "INSERT INTO submissions(top-submit, poster)
 VALUES ($actual_quote, $poster)";
?>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to ternary on your assignments, too:

```
$actual_quote = isset($_GET['actual_quote']) ?: false;
```